# Dynamically resizing AVPlayer in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have an AVPlayer that gets loads in a trivial fashion in my iOS 10 app:

```
 let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

 let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
 controller.player = player

 present(controller, animated: true) {
   player.play()
 }
```

This opens a player which occupies the entire frame of the window. I'd like to ideally be able to have the player take up only half my screen so on the bottom half I can add other content. I want to give the user the capability to enlarge the player to full screen, perhaps via an overlay/button that I frequently see:

[image]

What's the best way to not have my `AVPlayer` take up the full screen? What documentation should I be reviewing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `present`, be a custom parent view controller and make the AVPlayerViewController your child view controller. Now, provided you do the correct parent–child dance, you can just set the `frame` of the AVPlayerViewController's view and add it as a subview to your view. The view retains the ability for the user to send it into fullscreen mode (it will have the double-arrow button that you show in your screenshot).

Comment: Downloadable example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch15p660EmbeddedAVKit/EmbeddedAVKit/ViewController.swift